# jquery script doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('a.locked').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.button2").click(function(){
        $("a").removeClass("locked");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="example.com"target="_blank" id="action2">
  <button class="button2">
    <span class="icon">CLICK HERE</span>
  </button>
  <br>
  <br>
</a>
<a href="example.com"class="locked">
  <button class="locked-button">
    <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="icon">CONTINUE</span>
  </button>
</a>
```

I want that the last a element is locked, and if you click on the 2nd button, the class locked will be removed from the last a element and I will be able to click on the link.

It deletes the class but I still can't click the link. How to fix that?

Also, is there are smarter way to do that...

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: what jquery version?

Comment: Also, just a side note, wrapping a button in an anchor tag is not valid.

Comment: @palaѕн Please do not advise people to post code example on external sites as those links can become invalid over time. Advise people to post their code samples right here.

Comment: but the button works, like I have the same things just with an font awesome class you see the <i> element and it works

Comment: Some of the attributes in the anchor tag do not have spaces between them. Fix that first. i.e.`href="example.com"target="_blank"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, just removing a css class will not work in your case. 
You should [remove the event handler](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to allow the button to be clicked, something like this should work:

```
$("a.locked").on("click.locked", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.button2").click(function(){
        $("a.locked").off("click.locked");
        $("a").removeClass("locked");
    });
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpgfob5p/).

Answer (score 3):

This event binding isn't removed from the `<a>` when its `class="locked"` is removed:

```
$('a.locked').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

At least with direct bindings like this, jQuery only uses the selector initially to attach the event handler to all matching elements. It won't recheck the selector when the event is later triggered. Currently, you'll have to do that check yourself:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('locked')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Though, if you have an overall parent element, you can use a delegated binding and jQuery will then recheck the (2nd) selector for you when the event is triggered.

```
<div id="parent">
  <a href="example.com" target="_blank" id="action2">
    <!-- ... -->
  </a>
  <a href="example.com" class="locked">
    <!-- ... -->
  </a>
</div>
```

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'a.locked', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
Check out this SO question to read more about the `toggle` function I used.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#ToggleLock", function(e) {
   $('#Continue').prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
     return !v;
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id='ToggleLock'>Unlock/Lock</button>
<button onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'" type="button" id='Continue' disabled>Continue</button>
```

Let me know if I have greatly misunderstood the question.

Comment: I used onclick before, but I work with php and it doesnt execute the link from the database between in the onclick section

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class is not enough, since you added a click event to all `$('a.locked')` you need use `.off()` to remove the click event after removing the class. Also try to target the specific element, you could add `id="btn_continue"` to 2nd button. (`$("a")` will target all `<a>` which is not what you want to do)

Note:

```js
$('a.locked').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.button2").click(function(){
        $("#btn_continue").off().removeClass("locked");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="example.com" target="_blank" id="action2">
  <button class="button2">
    <span class="icon">CLICK HERE</span>
  </button>
  <br>
  <br>
</a>
<a href="example.com" id="btn_continue" class="locked">
  <button class="locked-button">
    <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="icon">CONTINUE</span>
  </button>
</a>
```